# Figure out IP address of external device

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, netstat

I have an external device (a PCB crate) of which I do not know the IP address. Connected to this device is a PCB that broadcasts its MAC address. Ultimately, I want to know this MAC address.

I can connect to PCB crate with an Ethernet cable. I have two Ethernet cards in my PC, one connected to the outside world (`eth0`), and one connected to the PCB crate (`eth1`).

I installed wireshark to see if I get any traffic on `eth1`, but I don't see anything. I suspect that I haven't set up the `eth1` Ethernet card correctly. Here's what `ifconfig` tells me:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4D:AA:E6:1D  
          inet addr:128.141.223.194  Bcast:128.141.223.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:4dff:feaa:e61d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1039531 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:342830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:339291866 (323.5 MiB)  TX bytes:150976185 (143.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:CA:26:B7:6F  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe26:b76f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:3190800 (3.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7cc0000-f7ce0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:96520 (94.2 KiB)  TX bytes:96520 (94.2 KiB)
```

Here's the output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:4d:aa:e6:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 128.141.223.194/24 brd 128.141.223.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::222:4dff:feaa:e61d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:05:ca:26:b7:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fe26:b76f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 52:54:00:bb:7f:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:bb:7f:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I see that `eth1` has an IP6 address, but not an IP4 address. I don't know if that is a problem. I tried to assign an IP4 address with

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but I do not see this address assigned to `eth1`. Moreover, I do not know what IP address the PCB crate has, so I don't know how I can communicate with it.

How can I figure out what IP address the PCB crate has? How can I communicate with it, such that the MAC address of the PCB will be broadcasted to my Ethernet card?

Comment: I'm guessing this is Linux. Does `ip addr` show the address getting assigned correctly? Linux's `ifconfig` is unfortunately very outdated.

Comment: Did you powercycle the crate while it was plugged in and wireshark was running? At boot time often when devices try and talk around them.

Comment: @grawity I added the output of `ip addr`.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I tried to power-cycle the crate while wireshark is running. I get no output at all.

Comment: Seems like you have two problems - unable to assign and ip, and determining whether it is even receiving packets. The latter you can test with something else.  If you have another device, put it on eth1 and turn it on and see if you get data.

Comment: @Paul I now realized that I can assign an IP address to the device, and `ip addr` is showing it correctly, but for some reason it loses its address again after a while.

Comment: Perhaps you have a dhcp service running for that interface?

Comment: @Paul I think that might be it. How can I turn off dhcp for only one device?

Comment: I'm on CentOS, if that matters.